# Filtering an array of objects against another object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that i need to filter by a certain criteria. I'm having trouble figuring out the logic for the if statement within the for loop. I've attached a code snippet where you can adjust the criteria and see the problem I'm trying to solve. Any thoughts or advice are greatly appreciated, thanks!

With the following criteria I should only end up with 1 found item in my foundItems array:

```
const criteria = {
    title: 'title',
    character: 'Z',
    type: ['second'],
};
```

This should(and does) return all three items:

```
const criteria = {
    title: 'title',
    character: '',
    type: [],
};
```

This should return the first two items:

```
const criteria = {
    title: 'title',
    character: 'R',
    type: [],
};
```

This should return all three items:

```
const criteria = {
    title: '',
    character: '',
    type: ['first','second'],
};
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        label: {
            title: 'A title',
        },
        character: 'R',
        type: 'first',
    },
    {
        label: {
            title: 'Another title',
        },
        character: 'R',
        type: 'second',
    },
    {
        label: {
            title: 'A more interesting title',
        },
        character: 'Z',
        type: 'second',
    },
];

const criteria = {
    title: 'title',
    character: 'Z',
    type: ['second'],
};

const createRegEx = (value) => {
  const regex = value
    .split(' ')
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map((word) => `(?=^.*${word})`)
    .join('');

  return new RegExp(regex, 'i');
}

const foundItems = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const item = data[i];
  
  if (
    item.label.title.match(createRegEx(criteria.title))
    || item.character === criteria.character
    || criteria.type.includes(item.type)
  ) {
    foundItems[foundItems.length] = item;
  }
}

console.log(foundItems);
```

Comment: Don't you have to match all 3 criteria?  Use `&&` rather than `||` ?

Comment: Both, kinda... All criteria are optional but if they exist then it's && and not ||. I think that's the part I'm stuck on. If I set it to && but i only have 1 of the criteria I get 0 items back. Make sense?

Comment: Ok. thanks. You may be over complicating a little. Let me gaze a little longer.

Comment: the string `title` exists in all three data elements. So the given criteria and the logical OR will end up with all three selected. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the intent of using an array for `type` criteria while the data element for type is a `string` type?

Comment: I genericized the model, the property names are for example only. EDIT: to clarify, the criteria type array could have multiple strings: type: ['first','second'] - i'll update the question with this

Comment: I'm thinking I need to break out the for loop in separate methods for each criteria then use && in the if statements

Comment: Then I'll generalized my answer: Your code does exactly what you ask of it - it returns results based upon the criteria provided.

Comment: I'm not sure you do. you just need to be clear describing your expected inputs=>/outputs - when you do that I'll be happy to explain how to do this very simply.

Comment: Great - given your edit, it is clear that your intention is to use AND rather than OR. In the example that should return only two. The `title` must contain `title` AND the `character` should be `R` AND the type can be anything.  This will select only the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demonstrates what I believe to be your intent. Please let me know if it needs to be corrected. I took some liberty to simplify the code a bit but I didn't know if the use of regex was a requirement.

The filter method applies a filter against each data element, if the filter *criteria*, to coin a phrase, match, returning true retains the element.

The ternary operators are necessary to determine if an input is relevant to the match. if empty then data is not filtered on that criteria.

This last point is what I believe you were missing:

```js
const data = [
    {
        label: {
            title: 'A title',
        },
        character: 'R',
        type: 'first',
    },
    {
        label: {
            title: 'Another title',
        },
        character: 'R',
        type: 'second',
    },
    {
        label: {
            title: 'A more interesting title',
        },
        character: 'Z',
        type: 'second',
    },
];

const criteria = {
    title: '',
    character: 'R',
    type: ['second'],
};

const foundItems = data.filter(item=>{
  let t = (criteria.title.length)
            ? item.label.title.includes(criteria.title)
            : true;
  let c = (criteria.character.length)
            ? item.character === criteria.character
            : true;
  let p = (criteria.type.length)
           ? criteria.type.includes(item.type)
           : true;
  return t && c && p;
});
console.log(foundItems);
```

Comment: This is exactly my intent. Thank you very much!